# Add Event to Calendar of another user using Google::Api::V3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am creating a web application that has the following classes. `User`'s  and `Booking`'s.  I need to give the ability to cleaner users to approve bookings which will in turn create an event on the hosts calendar.

Users have two types, `cleaners` and `hosts` . Each user has a calendar.

I have two uses cases that I am finding difficult to satisfy.

1. A Host accepts a cleaners `Booking` request; when this happens the `Booking` status is changed to approved and an event is added to the Hosts calendar.  This step works as it should becuase the `current_user` is the `host`, whom is authorized through oauth to make changes to their calendar.

```
def new_event(start, endd, cleaner)
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.update!(session[:authorization])
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.authorization = client
    calendar = service.get_calendar(:primary)
    today = Date.today
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
      start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: start),
      end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: endd),
      summary: "Cleaning Scheduled by #{cleaner}"
    })
    service.insert_event(calendar.id, event)
  end
```

I call that method here

```
def approve
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.update(status:'approved')
      if @booking.save
        flash[:success] = "Reservation Approved"
        # send_approved_booking_notification(@booking)
        new_event(@booking.starts_at.to_date,@booking.starts_at.to_date, @booking.cleaner.name)
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      else
```

2. A Host requests a cleaner and the cleaner approves the booking, when
   the cleaner approves, an event should be posted to the host
   calendar; Currently, the event is only added to the currently
   authorized users calendar, which is the cleaners calendar in this
   case. How can I post this event to the calendar of the user that
   created the request (the host)?

**TLDR;**

how do i add an event from one users calendar to another users calendar using Google::Api::CalendarV3?

Comment: I've read that a Google Service Account may be what I need but I'm not positive that is the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was adding an `attendee` to the params of my new event. I specified the email of the `host` in this case and the event was added to both the cleaners calendar and the host's calender. Here's my `new_event` method that inserts the event into both calendars

```
def new_event(start, endd, cleaner, host)
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.update!(session[:authorization])
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.authorization = client
    calendar = service.get_calendar(:primary)
    today = Date.today
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
      start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: start),
      end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: endd),
      attendees: [{email: host.email}],
      summary: "Cleaning Scheduled by #{cleaner}"
    })
    service.insert_event(calendar.id, event)
end
```